# Add VB Web Forms pages to MVC 5 C# Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-mvc-5

I've seen it's possible to mix VB and C# in a Website Project (WSP) by having code in the App_Code folder, but I cannot find any references to add be able to add Webforms pages (in VB) to an existing MVC web application project (WAP) that is in C#. This may sound weird to do, but we have legacy code that needs to be in a temporary working state while its being converted to MVC and C#. If the only way to do this is using a WSP project, could you please provide any examples of how to get the MVC integrated? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot mix VB and C# in the same project.  It would need to be a separate project and you would need to reference the dll.  That said, this really isn't a great idea.  Choose a consistent, single language for a project and stick to it.  Otherwise you're just asking for maintainability issues and inconsistencies.  Not to mention that mixing WebForms and MVC in the same project isn't a great idea either.

Comment: It's possible to use Web Forms pages in an MVC project but, as @DavidL has said, you'd still need to use the same programming language in each. Only one compiler is used to build a project and output an assembly so only one language can be used.  You would be able to mix languages in a Web Site project because they are not compiled. It sounds like you'll need to convert to C# in the Web Site and then you can start implementing MVC with Web Forms pages included.

Comment: Are there any examples of converting a Website Project (WSP) to MVC 5 and C#? When I try to create a new WSP, the only close choice I have is ASP.NET Web SIte (Razor v3) but all the MVC stuff is missing.  I'm guessing all the model and controller code needs to be in the App_Code folder?